# Pretty Paths in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, seo

I have a category model and I'm routing it using the default scaffolding of `resources :categories`. I'm wondering if there's a way to change the paths from `/category/:id` to `/category/:name`. I added:

```
match "/categories/:name" => "categories#show"
```

above the resources line in `routes.rb` and changed the `show` action in the controller to do:

```
@category = Category.find_by_name(params[:name])
```

it works, but the 'magic paths' such as `link_to some_category` still use the `:id` format.

Is there a way to do this? If this is a bad idea (due to some possible way in which rails works internally), is there another way to accomplish this? So that `/categories/music`, for example, and `/categories/3` both work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails has a nifty model instance method called `to_param`, and it's what the paths use. It defaults to `id`, but you can override it and produce something like:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    name
  end
end

cat = Category.find_by_name('music')
category_path(cat)  # => "/categories/music"
```

For more info, check the [Rails documentation for to_param](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-to_param).

EDIT:

When it comes to category names which aren't ideal for URLs, you have multiple options. One is, as you say, to `gsub` whitespaces with hyphens and vice versa when finding the record. However, a safer option would be to create another column on the categories table called `name_param` (or similar). Then, you can use it instead of the name for, well, all path and URL related business. Use the `parameterize` inflector to create a URL-safe string. Here's how I'd do it:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :create_name_param

  def to_param
    name_param
  end

  private
    def create_name_param
      self.name_param = name.parameterize
    end
end

# Hypothetical
cat = Category.create(:name => 'My. Kewl. Category!!!')
category_path(cat)  # => "/categories/my-kewl-category"

# Controller
@category = Category.find_by_name_param(param[:id]) # <Category id: 123, name: 'My. Kewl. Category!!!'>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had forgotten about this!

Comment: Do you by any chance know of a good way to handle spaces in categories? So for example, a category "two words", make it be "two-words" in the url? Would that entail me doing to_param name.gsub(" ", "-") and then each time I want to find_by_name I do the same thing? params[:name].gsub("-", " ")? How would I rewrite my match pattern though?

Comment: I found that there is a [parameterize](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Inflections.html#M001063) method in rails which should work better than the gsub'ing I was thinking about.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot vonconrad, that makes a lot of sense. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to to break existing code that relying on model id you could define your to_param like this:

```
 def to_param
   "#{id}-#{name}"
 end
```

so your url will be: http://path/1-some-model and you still can load your model with Model.find(params[:id]) because:

> > "123-hello-world".to_i
> >     => 123

Answer (score 1):

Although possibly more than you need, you may also want to look into 'human readable urls' support like friendly_id or one of the others (for instance, if you need unicode support, etc.) that are described [here at Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_permalinks___slugs.html).