# How to make URL routing like "web.com/user-name"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing

I have a basic app in Rails 3.2 - two main controllers: **users** and **articles**.
The basic routing is like **web.com/users/john** and **web.com/articles/articles-name**.

With the **match** rule I can make the URLs above shorter:

```
match "u/:permalink" => "users#my_action_name"
match "a/:permalink" => "articles#my_action_name"
```

allow me to do
**web.com/u/john** and **web.com/a/articles-name**

But in the best way, I would like to make the URL yet shorter and more readable, like this (this way use for instance Twitter - **twitter.com/username**)
**web.com/john** and **web.com/articles-name**

But I can't imagine, how to realize this way of routing. In the app are used also another controllers, like for example **HomeController** with actions **index**, **about**, **contact**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the "[Route Globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing)" section of the official Rails guides. You need to add something like

```
match '*users_or_articles' => 'agnostic#show'
```

at the end of your `config/routes.rb` file. This will catch all request that found no matchers in your routes file so far. Then your controller has to identify what to do with the request.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same thing some time ago and found an answer in the [Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Your question can be answered in 2 steps:

1) First step would be to override the `to_param` method in your models in order to have prettier URLs. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732779/pretty-paths-in-rails) for an example. You could also use a gem like FriendlyId (take a look at this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast)).

2) Then you would have to use the `:path` option in your `routes.rb` file. So for example if you wanted to have URLs like "example.com/3214-a-blog-post" you should declare your resource like this:

```
resources :posts, :path => "/"
```